# C function pointer syntax

Tags: c, declare

Normally, when declaring some variable, you put its type before it, like:

```
int a;
```

a function pointer may have type like: `int(*)(int,int)`, in case we point to a function that takes two integers and returns an integer. But, when declaring such a pointer, its identifier is not after the type, like:

```
int(*)(int,int) mypointer;
```

instead, you must write the identifier in the middle:

```
int(*mypointer)(int,int);
```

why is this so?

Comment: Search for "Declaration reflects use".

Comment: This Q helps explain Typedef syntax `typedef old-type alias-identifier` but example function pointer examples like "typedef int (*sum_func)(int,int);" don't match the syntax... Until now!

Comment: Because the language is badly designed. That's it!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I explain this in my answer to [Why was the C syntax for arrays, pointers, and functions designed this way?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/117024/why-was-the-c-syntax-for-arrays-pointers-and-functions-designed-this-way/117039#117039), and it basically comes down to:

> the language authors preferred to make the syntax variable-centric rather than type-centric. That is, they wanted a programmer to look at the declaration and think "if I write the expression `*func(arg)`, that'll result in an `int`; if I write `*arg[N]` I'll have a float" rather than "`func` must be a pointer to a function taking *this* and returning *that*".
>
> The [C entry on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)#Criticism) claims that:
>
> Ritchie's idea was to declare identifiers in contexts resembling their use: "declaration reflects use".
>
> ...citing p122 of K&R2.

Answer (score 30):

This structure reflects how a normal function is declared (and used).

Consider a normal function definition:

```
int foo (int bar, int baz, int quux);
```

Now consider defining a function pointer to a function of the same signature:

```
int (*foo) (int, int, int);
```

Notice how the two structures mirror each other? That makes `*foo` much easier to identify as a function pointer rather than as something else.

Answer (score 21):

If you're dealing with a function (not a pointer to one), the name is in the middle too. It goes like: `return-type function-name "(" argument-list ")" ...`. For example, in `int foo(int)`, `int` is the return type, `foo` the name and `int` the argument list.

A pointer to a function works pretty much the same way -- return type, then name, then argument list. In this case, we have to add a `*` to make it a pointer, and (since the `*` for a pointer is prefix) a pair of parentheses to bind the `*` to the name instead of the return type. For example, `int *foo(int)` would mean a function named foo that takes an int parameter and returns a pointer to an int. To get the * bound to `foo` instead, we need parentheses, giving  `int (*foo)(int)`.

This gets particularly ugly when you need an array of pointers to functions. In such a case, most people find it easiest to use a typedef for the pointer type, then create an array of that type:

```
typedef int (*fptr)(int);

fptr array[10];
```

Answer (score 11):

I had seen at some places function pointers declared as

```
int (*foo) (int a, int b);
```

and at some places `a` and `b` are not mentioned and both still works.

so

```
int (*foo) (int, int)
```

is also correct.

A very simple way that I found to remember is as mentioned below:

Suppose function is declared as:

```
int function (int a , int b);
```

**Step1:** Simply put function in parentheses:

```
int (function) (int a , int b);
```

**Step2:** Place a `*` in front of function name and change the name:

```
int (*funcPntr) (int a , int b);
```

PS: I am not following proper coding guidelines for naming convention etc. in this answer.

Comment: Both `int (*foo) (int a, int b);` and `int (*foo) (int, int);` works because a parameter's name in a function prototype is optional in C.