# type of function pointer

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I have a short program with which I am going to test the “infinite recursion”. However, I meet another tough question associated to function pointer...

the program is as follow:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int repeat(char (*func)(int, int), int a) {
  func(a, a+1);
  return repeat(func, a+1);
}

char f (int a , int b){
  printf("%d\n", a);
  //return (double)(a + b);
  return 'c';
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  repeat(&f, 1);
  return 0;
}
```

As for me, I think the 'f' in “**repeat(&f, 1)**” has the type of “**char ***” and the 'func' in “**int repeat(char (*func)(int, int), int a)**” has the type of “**char ***”,too.

However, it seems strange. If I change “**(char (*func)(int, int), int a)** ” to 
“**(char func(int, int), int a)** ”, the compiler(testing in gcc and vc6) do not give any warnings and the running result is the same.

If I change  “**(char (*func)(int, int), int a)** ” to “**(double func(int, int), int a)** ”, 
the compiler throws:

*warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'char (*)(int, int)' to parameter of type 'double (*)(int, int)' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types] repeat(&f, 1);*

It seems that the compiler treat “**double (int, int)**” and “**double (*)(int, int)**” the same stuff. In other words, If I change “**(char (*func)(int, int), int a)**” to “**double (*func)(int, int)**”, the compiler will throw the same message (I have tested it):

*warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'char (*)(int, int)' to parameter of type 'double (*)(int, int)' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types] repeat(&f, 1);*

God...
Well, it is not the end.
After that, I change the “**repeat(&f, 1)**” **to “repeat(f, 1)**” with other parts unchanged.
That is, the whole program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int repeat(char (*func)(int, int), int a) {
  func(a, a+1);
  return repeat(func, a+1);
}

char f (int a , int b){
  printf("%d\n", a);
  //return (double)(a + b);
  return 'c';
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  repeat(f, 1);
  return 0;
}
```

the compiler do not give any warnings and the running results are the same.

So I am confused that all of the following paris yields no warnings and correct results.

```
    1   repeat(&f, 1)   int repeat(char (*func)(int, int), int a)
    2   repeat(&f, 1)   int repeat(char func(int, int), int a) 
    3   repeat(f, 1)    int repeat(char (*func)(int, int), int a) 
    4   repeat(f, 1)    int repeat(char func(int, int), int a)
```

Of course the 'f' in “**repeat(f, 1)**” has the type of “**char (int, int)**”, and the 'func' in "**int repeat(double (*func)(int, int), int a)***" has the type of “**char ()(int, int)**”.

You can infer this by changing “**int repeat(char (*func)(int, int), int a)** ” to “**int repeat(double (*func)(int, int), int a)** ” and check the warning message:

*warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'char (int, int)' to parameter of type 'double (*)(int, int)' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types] repeat(f, 1);*

Who can give some comments? I totally think that only the first of the four is correct regarding the type.

Comment: there's no `char *` involved in this code whatsoever. `char (*)(int, int)` is a pointer to function returning a `char` and taking two `int` arguments. Also, http://cdecl.org.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C function pointer syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114749/c-function-pointer-syntax)

Comment: Notice that the type system of C is not able to declare a non-variadic function which accepts itself as a function parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Type of the parameter:**

The order of precendence imposed by `()` in the syntax of :

```
    int repeat(char (*func)(int, int), int a)
```

means that `(*func)(int,int)` is a function taking two `int` arguments and returning a `char`.  The `*` means that `func` a pointer to a function returning `char`.

The following more modern syntax would have worked as well :

```
    int repeat(char func(int, int), int a)
```

ATTENTION, the following looks close to the first one, but would be totally different, the function argument would be a pointer to a function returning a `char *`:

```
    int repeat(char *func(int, int), int a)
```

And yes, just for completeness, `int repeat((char *)func(int, int), int a)` would be a syntax error, as `(char*)` would be understood as a cast operator whereas a type is expected.

**Use of the f and &f syntax:**

The **C11 standard** section 6.5.3.2 states that "*The unary `&` operator yields the address of its operand. If the operand has type ‘‘type’’, the result has type ‘‘pointer to type’’*":

- `f` being a function taking two `int` as argument and returning a `char`
- So `&f` is a pointer to a function taking two `int` as argument and returning a `char`.

But the standard in section 6.3.2.1/4 also states that "*A function designator is an expression that has function type. (...) a function designator with type ‘‘function returning type’’ is converted to an expression that has type ‘‘pointer to function returning type’’*":

- `f` being a function taking two `int` as argument and returning a `char`
- if provided in an expression (of course not in the syntax of a function call), `f` is also understood as pointer to a function taking two `int` as argument and returning a `char`.

Nowadays, you'll find both syntaxes.

Historically speaking, in former times the use of `*` in the `(*func)()` syntax was mandatory to call the function pointed to (see original K&R).

Comment: Thank you very much, it is surprising that you have known so much even about the C standard/C11 standard. really cool.
So, they are different in the past, but the same nowadays?

Comment: Maybe that's the way mainstream languages evolve ?  New syntaxes emerge, but old ones are kept because of the huge code base.  Then it's a matter of taste: some will prefer `extern char rpt(char(*)(int, int));` and some `extern char rpt(char(int, int));`

Comment: Mostly a nice answer, but your last sentence is inaccurate.  I have my copy of K&R 1st Edition, and it covers pointers to functions on pp114-117.  Not one of the function names used as a function pointer is preceded by an `&`; it was not legal at the time (but was made legal by C89, still over a decade into the future when the book was written).  Also, in K&R 1, the only way to invoke a pointer to function as a function was `(*pointer_to_func)(arg1, arg2)`; again, standard C allowed the shorthand `pointer_to_func(arg1, arg2)`.

Comment: Note how the use-mimics-type applies in `(*func)(a1, a2)`, which matches a declaration such as `int (*func)(int a1, int a2)` which tells the compiler that the return type of `(*func)(a1, a2)` is `int`.  The new notation has some merits, but you lose the certainty about whether `some_name(a1, a2)` is an invocation of a function such as `int some_name(int a1, int a2)` or function pointer (perhaps from a function argument list) `int (*some_name)(int a1, int a2)`.  With the old system, it was crystal clear; with the new, not so much.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Indeed ! In K&R1 p.115 the example is without & : `sort(lineptr, nlines, strcmp,swap)` the two last being functions.  Nevertheless it states just below that "*& is not **necessary***".  My appologies. I was mistaken by another difference:  the `*` was mandatory in the `(*fptr)(...)` calling syntax which is no longer the case.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, @Christophe.
So the old usage is: when passing a function pointer as an argument, we do not use `&`; when invoking a pointer to function as a function we use `*`. And it is much more clear than the new usage. I am not sure whether I understand it well. (My native language is not English...)

Comment: @ZirunZhu: whether it is clearer depends on your perspective. When I learned C, the `&` on the function name wasn't an option AFAICR, and you didn't ever write `&` in front of an array name because different C compilers interpreted it differently.  This was a murky area that the standard fixed.  A lot of C works on 'type mimics use'.  When you write `int *ip;`, it means that if you subsequently use `*ip`, the type is `int`.  Similarly with function pointers: if you declare `int (*func)(int a1, int a2)`, then `(*func)(1, 2)` produces an `int`.  These days, you can write `func(1, 2)` as well.

Answer (score 3):

When used as a function parameter, both of the syntax

```
foo(char bar(int, int), int a)
```

and

```
foo(char (*bar)(int, int), int a)
```

are identical from the compiler's standpoint.

Also note that when you call function `foo`, the name of the function passed to it is treated as pointer to that function. These both calls are valid

```
foo(&f, 1)
foo(f, 1)
```

> As for me, I think the `f` in `repeat(&f, 1)` has the type of `char *` and the `func` in `int repeat(char (*func)(int, int), int a)` has the type of `char *`,too.

No . `f` and `func` both are of type `char (*)(int, int)`, i.e. they are ***pointer to a function that takes two `int` as argument and returns `char`***

Comment: Thanks! I got the answer when I returned home from workplace... In fact, should they be the same! (The answer from Christophe seems more complete, so I vote him, you already have the reputation of 33.2k : ) you geek.)

Comment: “f and func both are of type char (*)(int, int), i.e. they are pointer to a function that takes two int as argument and returns char”.
Thank you again. The type is char (*)(int, int) indeed. I made a silly mistake.