# Declaring a block as typedef

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I keep seeing block declarations like this:

```
typedef returnType (^TypeName)(parameterTypes);
```

And I would like to know, why would I declare a block as a typedef?

Comment: To make it easier to use in method parameter definitions and variable declarations.  This is useful reference: http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com/

Comment: So, I can just declare it as a typedef and use it wherever I want, instead of declaring it as a local variable or a method parameters? @AnnaDickinson

Comment: Yup, as long as the typedef is defined in that scope (I.e. Its header is imported).

Comment: Sweet! Now I get it :), thank you very much!! @AnnaDickinson.

Comment: Declare a property with block type, and you'll be most grateful for the typedef.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it that way to reduce the likelihood of typos and make the code more readable.
For an extreme example, see my answer here: [Syntax to define a Block that takes a Block and returns a Block in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27162567/syntax-to-define-a-block-in-objective-c/27162860#27162860)