# Is it possible to use a single typedef to define a block that takes no parameters and returns a block?

Tags: objective-c

Similar/Follow-up to this question:
[Syntax to define a Block that takes a Block and returns a Block in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27162567/syntax-to-define-a-block-that-takes-a-block-and-returns-a-block-in-objective-c)

I understand that this wouldn't be something that I would want to do but I want to understand why I can't use a single typedef to define:

```
typedef void (^XYZSimpleBlock)(void);
typedef XYZSimpleBlock (^ComplexBlock)(void);
```

Why is the above valid but this is not valid?

```
typedef void(^)(void) (^ComplexBlock)(void);
```

If I go by a similar answer I found I can try and parse it like a compiler but I am a bad compiler.

Following C's left-right-rule wouldn't the first identifier be `ComplexBlock`?

```
typedef void(^)(void) (^ComplexBlock)(void);
// parser reads left right and finds ComplexBlock first
```

Then it would go right and find the close of the declaration, then left until it find the caret, then right to interpret the parameters list.

That brings us to

```
 typedef void(^)(void) (^ComplexBlock)(void);
//       | unhandled   |compiled/interpreted|
```

What is happening at this point that it can't read the `void(^)(void)` as a return type?

The thing that's confusing to me is that using a typedef is basically just a `#define` so shouldn't it be basically the same as above?

```
typedef void (^XYZSimpleBlock)(void);
same as:
void(^)(void)    
so:
typedef XYZSimpleBlock (^ComplexBlock)(void);
should be the same as:
typedef void(^)(void) (^ComplexBlock)(void);
```

I'm missing something here...

Comment: This is not C code! I think you may leave the c-tag.

Comment: good call, removing. I thought it may have had to do with the underlying c compiler but probably not enough to justify the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
typedef void (^(^ComplexBlock)(void))(void);
```

As you construct declarations of complex types like this, it can help to start with the simpler type and substitute "expressions" for the identifier.

So, for example, declaring a function that takes no arguments and returns `void`:

```
void a_func(void);
```

Now, we want to declare a function pointer `a_func_ptr` which is a pointer to the same type of function. We want the expression `*a_func_ptr` to be of the same type as `a_func`, so we drop that expression, in parentheses, into the above and get:

```
void (*a_func_ptr)(void);
```

If we want a block pointer instead of a function pointer, we use `^` instead of `*`:

```
void (^a_block_ref)(void);
```

(One reason why people find block syntax frustrating is that one never actually writes the expression `^a_block_ref` to "dereference" a block variable, so making that leap is non-obvious.)

Taking the above and making a `typedef` out of it (rather than a variable declaration) is how you get your:

```
typedef void (^XYZSimpleBlock)(void);
```

But, for a moment, let's go back to the function pointer `a_func_ptr`. Suppose you want to declare a function `func_returns_func` that returns a function pointer. You drop the function call expression in where `a_func_ptr` is. That is, you drop `func_returns_func()` in:

```
void (*func_returns_func())(void);
```

Now, when declaring functions, you need to use `void` for no arguments, so you make that:

```
void (*func_returns_func(void))(void);
```

Note that you do not gather or isolate the return type to the left of the identifier. It surrounds the identifier.

Now you change the `*` to a `^` to get a function which returns a block reference instead of a function pointer:

```
void (^func_returns_block(void))(void);
```

Let's make a pointer to a function that returns a block reference. Drop `(*ptr_to_func_returns_block)` in for `func_returns_block` and get:

```
void (^(*ptr_to_func_returns_block)(void))(void);
```

Again, replace `*` with `^` to get a reference to a block which returns a block reference:

```
void (^(^block_returns_block)(void))(void);
```

And there we are. Just change the name and that's how you get:

```
void (^(^ComplexBlock)(void))(void);
```

Comment: *slow clap* great description. Follow-up question, what is the difference between a block ref and a function ptr memory-wise? Is it that there is shared memory for methods and new memory for each block since they're objects? Is that a fair characterization?

Comment: Well, technically, that's an implementation detail. In practice, a function pointer is just the address of the first instruction of the function's code. A block reference is a pointer to an object which tracks a function pointer for the anonymous function for the block's code, any captured variables, and other bookkeeping stuff. For either, the code is typically static. It's part of the executable and when that was loaded, the code was loaded. I think that's what you mean by "shared memory", although that term usually means something else.