# What does this C pointer code do?

Tags: c, pointers

I've just came up with this code on minute 1:06 of [a coursera lecture](https://www.coursera.org/learn/software-security/lecture/qpYj6/type-safety). What does it do?

```
int (*cmp)(char*, char*);
```

Comment: In general, I find this one to be quite good explanation of pointers: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028000.do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C function pointer syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114749/c-function-pointer-syntax)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**This is a pointer to a function where the function returns an int and takes as argument two character pointers.**

---

The basic rule boils down to few things:-

There are three simple steps to follow:

- Starting with the unknown element, move in a spiral/clockwise direction; when ecountering the following elements replace them with the corresponding english statements: `[X] or []`

  1. Array `X` size of... or Array undefined size of...`(type1, type2)`
  2. function passing `type1` and `type2` returning...
     *
  3. pointer(s) to... Keep doing this in a spiral/clockwise direction until all tokens have been covered. Always resolve anything in parenthesis first!

Reference: **<sub>1.[Clockwise-rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)</sub>**
**<sub>2.[right-left rule](http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html)</sub>**

Answer (score 6):

When you read C declarations you must read them [butrophedonically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boustrophedon) (common way of writing in stone in Ancient Greece).

```
pointer to
  function that 
    has (char*, char*) type parameters as input
    and int as output
```

EDIT:

Answer (score 1):

The code you have pasted is actually a pointer to a function. the [prototype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype) of the function could be:
 `int cmp (char*, char*);`

There are three parts in this function: the return type is an integer, the name of the function is  `cmp` and there are two arguments, all of which are a pointer to a character (array). Specifically, the function is used for sorting, for example, if the first argument is less than the second one, the function will return a negative number, if equal, return zero, and if greater, return a positive number. For example, if I have the following code:

```
char c1 = 'a';
char c2 = 'b';
int result = cmp(&c1, &c2);
```

Then The result will be a negative number, e.g. -1, because 'a' is less than 'b'. In the function call above, I added & before each argument, because the argument data type are pointers/references to the character.  `&` is an operation to get the address of the variable.

With regards to the code you've provided, there is actually an additional  `*` before the name of the function  `cmp`. That means you want to get the reference of the entire function, rather than any single variable or array. For example, the following is the prototype of the function [qsort](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm) in C:

`void qsort(void *base, size_t nitems, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void *, const void*))`

The third argument of this function is actually very similar to the code you have provided. The reason to do so is you can directly pass a whole function to another function, e.g., qsort, as an argument.

Take a look at of this [link](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/106/) for details about pointers in C.

I hope this answers your question.