# What is the difference between int (*cmp)(void) and int *cmp(void)?

Tags: c

What is the difference between

```c
extern int (*func)(void);
```

and

```c
extern int *func(void);
```

Thanks

Comment: One is a function pointer, and the other is a function returning an int pointer.

Comment: @PiRocks You could post that as the answer to the question. No more details are needed, really.

Comment: I guess this is more a off topic question for meta than for the comments, but this question seems like a duplicate to me. I was unable to quickly find what it is a duplicate of quickly though. So like it's a duplicate but not. So should it be flagged?

Comment: Seeing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114749/c-function-pointer-syntax/ and https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/117024/why-was-the-c-syntax-for-arrays-pointers-and-functions-designed-this-way/ I would also say it's a duplicate and should NOT be used as a ("looks OK") audit question!

Answer (score 7):

```
extern int (*func)(void);
```

declares `func` as a pointer to a function which takes no arguments and returns an `int` value.

```
extern int *func(void);
```

is a forward declaration (a.k.a. a protptype) of `func` as a function that takes no arguments and returns a pointer to an `int`.

The first declares a *variable*, the second declares a *function*.

Answer (score 2):

> difference between `int (*cmp)(void)` and `int *cmp(void)`?

Use [C gibberish ↔ English](https://cdecl.org) <sup>1</sup>

**Pointer Declaration**
`extern int (*cmp)(void);` is a [extern pointer to function (void) returning int](https://cdecl.org/?q=extern+int+%28*cmp%29%28void%29%3B).

**Function Declaration**
`extern int *cmp(void);` is a [extern function (void) returning pointer to int](https://cdecl.org/?q=extern+int+*cmp%28void%29%3B).

---

<sup>1</sup> "func" is a keyword there, use `"cmp".

Answer (score 1):

If you declare a type `fp` as pointer to a function, that the compiler will interpret `fp()` as dereferencing `fp` to get the address of the function.

Whereas, if `fp` is declared as the function itself, then any `fp()` in your file, will be interpret by the compiler as a near-call **to** the address of `fp`.

Meaning, that the linker will fix up the jump as the offset between the caller address, and the address of `fp` **itself**.

**Not** the address located at `fp`, but the offset **to** `fp`.

Comment: More like a near *call* rather than a near jump though.