# passing function to another function multiple variables c

Tags: c

```
void generate_sequence (int xs, int currentlen, int seqlen, int *seq);
void check_loop_iterative(void (*f)(?), int xs, int seqlen, int *loop, int *looplen);
```

I need to pass  first function to second function.So my question is.How should I fill the parameters where the question mark is?

Comment: `int,int,int,int*` spring to mind. That, going off the soothsaying assumption that *"I need to pass first function to second function."* actually means "I need to declare a function pointer parameter `f`, compatible with the first function, as the first parameter to the second function."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114749/c-function-pointer-syntax

Comment: @WhozCraig `int, int, int, *int` ?

Comment: @WhozCraig the last int should have an asterisk attached.

Comment: check_loop_iterative(generate_sequence(xs,curr_len,seqlen,seq),seqlen,loop,looplen);    I m calliing function like this but it gives an error where is my fault?

Comment: @anon88 `generate_sequence(xs,curr_len,seqlen,seq)` calls the function, rather than passing on the function pointer. It should be `check_loop_iterative(generate_sequence,seqlen,loop,looplen);` and then call generate_sequence through the function pointer later inside `check_loop_iterative`.

Answer (score 4):

This is how you deal with function pointers in a manner that will keep you sane:

- Write a `typedef` similar to the function declaration you want. In this case it's just about adding `typedef` in front and coming up with a meaningful type name:

  ```
  typedef void sequence_t (int xs, int currentlen, int seqlen, int *seq);
  ```

  It doesn't matter what you name the parameters to and you don't even need to name them, though you should ideally have all functions of this type using the same parameter names. So regard the `typedef` as a function template.
- To use a function pointer to this function type, simply do `sequence_t* ptr;`.

Answer (score -2):

> *How should I fill the parameters where the question mark is?*

You write the same list as the pointed function has:

```c
void generate_sequence (int xs, int currentlen, int seqlen, int *seq);

void check_loop_iterative(void (*f)(int /*xs*/, int /*currentlen*/, int /*seqlen*/, int* /*seq*/), int xs, int seqlen, int *loop, int *looplen);
```

The parameter names are not necessary, so I put them in comments.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31727629)

Comment: @jrswgtr I still think that the answer is correct in the first, dense form. Anyway, it is extended now.