# How to write `auto` explicitly when looping over a vector of function pointers?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a vector of function pointers and I want to loop over them:

```
vector<int (*)(int, int)>v;
//... push_back some function pointers 
for (auto func : v) { /* do stuff */ }
```

For educational purposes, I thought to write out the type that `auto` is discovered as, explicitly. So I tried this:

```
for (int (*)(int, int) func : v) { /* ... */} // [1]
```

... but it gives the compiler error "Expected an identifier". This is odd to me, because the apparently equivalent code below compiles and runs:

```
using funcZ2toZ = int (*)(int, int);
for (funcZ2toZ func : v) { /* ... */ }
```

What is the correct syntax for line [1] above?

Comment: The corerct syntax is `int (*func)(int, int)`. Trying to find a duplicate...

Comment: Ah of course, exactly like a normal declaration of such a function pointer. I'll leave the question open since you're already looking for a duplicate. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I can't find anything. This one is close I guess: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114749/c-function-pointer-syntax/

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I think that's a duplicate ... but I just walked in on this conversation, so I'll leave off with my hammer ...

Comment: Also, note that using `using` (or `typedef`) aliases for **function** pointers is one of the very few places where "hiding pointers behind aliases" is considered acceptable. Maybe even the *only* place.